# What is best approach to validate a Java bean against custom validation rules?

Tags: java, validation

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Here I want to validate these fields using custom rule set defined in database for each field.

e.g. validate length of `name` field - length validation can be different for different companies.

Scenario :
For company x, max length of name field can be 20.
For company y, max length of name field can be 30.
How to apply this validation criteria runtime?

Answer (score -1):

I see at least two approaches

## BeanValidation

Annotate field of your domain object (one you need to validate, User in your case) with annotations from `javax.validation.constraints package` https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html

To perform validation ,you need to obtain instance of javax.validation.Validator
and use it.

Sample code

```
void validate() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Msisdn>> violations = localValidatorFactoryBean.getValidator().validate(this);
        if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
        }
    }
```

It requires Spring Framework.  Note that constructing LocalValidatorFactoryBean is costly process.

Generally, `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` should be constructed once, at application startup.

`javax.xml.validation.Validator` should be `@Autowired` where needed.

Spring Framework+Spring Boot will manage all those details for you.

It is also possible to use java validation without Spring. Mandatory component is Validation Provider (JDK defines just interfaces, no implementation). Hibernate Validator is sample validation provider.

In this approach, you can perform your validation only in Spring-managed classes (services, controllers, etc).

This is not feasible solution for validating in constructor, in static methods.

## Guava preconditions

I used that when I was in need to perform validation from constructor.

See Preconditions from Guava library
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained

It exposes functions like

```
 Preconditions.checkNotNull(value, "value cannot be null");
 Preconditions.checkArgument(..)
```

You could validate arguments in setters, constructor, build() method in your builders- every time where object building is finished and invariants need to be checked.

In this scenario just Guava Library is required. It is not related to Java Validation API or implementation.

## Conditional validation

If you want your validation to depend on the context (not just on the class you are validating) then validation rules shoud not be placed on the class you are validating.

In Spring you could write Validator as external class.

```
public class PersonValidator implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return Person.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(e, "name", "name.empty");
        Person p = (Person) obj;
        if (p.getAge() < 0) {
            e.rejectValue("age", "negativevalue");
        } else if (p.getAge() > 110) {
            e.rejectValue("age", "too.darn.old");
        }
    }
}
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validator for more details.

Same principle (external class with validation logic) could be applied for Guava.

Then in your business logic you will be able to choose and use correct Validator.

Comment: Using the Java Bean Validation library requires neither Spring nor Guava, though both of those can work with it.

Comment: true. but my code sample uses LocalValidatorFactoryBean, which is Spring Component. Second sample (guava) is not releated to Java Bean Validation. Updated answer with details about dependencies for each scenario.

Comment: In fact, using Java Bean Validation requires a [JSR 303 framework](http://hibernate.org/validator/); Spring is not such a framework - it is a DI framework. It provides wrapper over JSR 303 for more convenient use.

Comment: true. Answer aleady states 'It is also possible to use java validation without Spring'.

Comment: My point is that Spring has as much to do with JSR 303 as it does with HTTP. I'm not quite sure why it's mentioned at all. It's like saying "_in order to add two numbers in Java one simply needs to add the Jython library and execute this simple script_" - whilst it might achieve the desired effect it's a bit of a [sledgehammer -> nut](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-sledgehammer-to-crack-a-nut) scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I am already using annotations to validate fields. I have added a scenario to explain my question better. How to apply rule sets dynamically on field of pojo?

Comment: Edited my answer with section how to perform conditional validation.